# Highcharts Line Chart Legend Symbol Disappeared When Using Gradient Fill

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to fill gradient color in my charts, with the sample code in the demo "http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient". And then I found in line charts' legend, the line part of the symbol disappeared, while the markers were still visible. If I disable the markers, then there is nothing left.

Here is an example based on the code of a line chart demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TCbE3/

```
enter code here
```

I'm using Highcharts 3.0.1, with both latest FireFox and Chrome, and this problem occurs in both.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: I think this is your [topic](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1936)

Comment: Yes this is my topic. I was hoping I could get some answers here..